# How to use Vue.js to template a Modal and reuse it?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

So currently I have a web app that loads a dashboard based on a SQL database and that works just fine, each of these elements have buttons and those buttons are SUPPOSED to spawn a modal with the content of the problem and you can interact with it etc.

Recently I have figured out how to use Vue.js to run a function that grabs this information and populate it on the modal. However, this modal can only be templated ONCE before it wont work again. Ex: I can click on problem 1 and problem 1's information is correct. however, if I click problem 2 after that it doesn't work

```
new Vue({
    delimiters: ['!!!','!!!'],
    el: '#problem-modal',
    methods: {
        close() {
            this.$emit('close');
            },
        },

    data: {
        items: [],
        name: null,
        summary: null,
    },
    mounted: function () {
        var self = this;
        fetch('./api/problems')
            .then(response => {
                var response = response.json();
                return response;
            })
            .then(json => {
                var data = json.data;
                var length = data.length;
                for (var i = 0; i<length; i++) {
                    if (data[i].unique_id == button_id) {
                        this.name = data[i].problem_name;
                        this.summary = data[i].summary;
                    }
                }
            })
    }
})
}
```

Here is my Script for the vue, assume that the problems load perfectly and this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="problem-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">!!! name !!!</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        !!! summary !!!
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

is the modal. Any idea on how to make the modal element able to be used more than once?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I give you nearest illustration of your question ! I thought `items` is your problem list . As you mentioned you have to clicked button so that pass your clicked data to call method and grab data from `items` with that pass clicked data and set vue data . I hope it will be ok .. Look at my example

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#problem-modal',
    methods: {
    show(id) {
       let cur = this.items.find(x => x.id == id);
       this.name = cur.name;
       this.summary = cur.summary;
    }
        },
    data: {
        items: [
          {
             id: 1,
             name: "one",
             summary: "one summary "
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: "two",
            summary : "two summary"
          }
        ],
        name: null,
        summary: null,
    }
});
```

```css
button {
width: 100%;
height: 20px;
margin: 10px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="problem-modal">
<button v-for="item in items" @click="show(item.id)">{{item.id}}</button>


<div class="modal">
  <h1>{{name}}</h1>
  <pre>{{summary}}</pre>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment! it seems to be helpful, however I do not want to hard code the items in such list and limit the amount of data transferred on webpage if at all possible, could I still use the api grabber to return such list on any given button press with some tinkering? I'm simply trying to make it as dynamic as I can to avoid large data transfers and slowdowns @David Jaw Hpan